# No Reconoce ruta Base del proyecto web MVC

Tags: javascript, json, controller, rutas, viewmodel

Estimados tengo el siguiente problema, en mi local cuando ejecuto un proyecto web la siguiente linea funciona correctamente:

```
$.getJSON("/Product/GetMesesList?area=Producto", { IdTipCon: $("#dllConsumo").val()  function (data) {
}
```

Esto me funcionaba bien también en el servidor, pero no se que pudo ocurrir que ahora me manda el error 404, al parecer no esta detectando el proyecto, por que en la linea de comando del explorer coloco
"`proyecto/Producto/GetMesesList?area=Producto`" y si me carga el resultado.

O como tendría que configurarlo.

Gracias

Comment: Estoy tratando de comprenderte, dices que esa línea de código te funcionaba en local y en el servidor pero a su vez no funciona en ninguno?

Comment: Aquí: `$.getJSON("/Product/GetMesesList?area=Producto"` usas `Product` y aquí: `proyecto/Producto/GetMesesList?area=Producto` usas `Producto`, por lo tanto, no estamos hablando de lo mismo. Supongo que no pones `proyecto` porque el archivo estaría en esa carpeta...

Comment: No, esa linea de comando si me funciona en mi local, pero no en el servidor, ahora lo que he hecho es ponerle $.getJSON("../Product/") y ahora me funciona bien. Lo que quiero entender es por que ahora tengo que poner los dos puntos cuando antes no era necesario. Gracias